# fetching page properties of root page to /apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler/Throwable.jsp

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, aem

I have a simple use case, as follows:

1. A 500 error is thrown in AEM
2. End user is redirected to /apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler/Throwable.jsp which has location of the 500 error page.
3. If I set  , it works fine.

However what I want to do is, create a pathfield in page properties advance tab so that authors can set the error 500 page at the root page.

such that:

if an 500 error is thrown at : /content/sitename/en/home/products/myproduct.html
Error 500 page property set at:       /content/sitename/en/
error 500 page is at /content/sitename/en/home/errors/500.jsp

CQ should search through the page tree structure bottom up from where the error is thrown to a place where error 500 page is set and then whereever it finds the first property of error handler set, it redirects it to that 500 page through the /apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler/Throwable.jsp.

so, in the  /apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler/Throwable.jsp, the full code is:

```
    <%@page session="false"
      import="com.day.cq.wcm.commons.WCMUtils"
      import="org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource"
      import="javax.jcr.Node"
      %>
      <%
     %><%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp" %>

     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

     <%
          String errorPage= WCMUtils.getInheritedProperty(currentPage,    resourceResolver, "errorrPageRedirect");
       %>

      <c:redirect url="${errorPage}"/>


        Doesn't seems to be working. Am I missing something ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/errorpagehandler.html ?

You can even specify different 404 pages for different paths.  I can't remember if there are limits on where the error pages have to be relative to the paths, but it fits your requirement.